# Consistency of categorical encodings in h2o (and R) for training and new test sample

Tags: r, h2o, categorical-data

I'm having trouble understanding whether I need to be consistent with the categorical / factor encodings of variables. With consistency I mean that I need to assure that the encodings from integers and levels should be the same in the training and the new testing sample.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595499/consistent-factor-levels-for-same-value-over-different-datasets) seems to suggest that it is not necessary. On the contrary, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872489/randomforest-does-not-work-when-training-set-has-more-different-factor-levels-th?rq=1) suggests that IT is indeed necessary.

Suppose I have a training sample with an `xcat` that can take values `a`, `b`, `c`. The expected result is that the `y` variable will tend to take values close to `1` when `xcat` is `a`, `2`when `xcat` is `b`, and `3` when `xcat` is `c`.

First I'll create the dataframe, pass it to `h2o` and then encode with the function `as.factor`:

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, startH2O = TRUE)

n = 20
y <- sample(1:3, size = n, replace = T)
xcat <- letters[y]
xnum <- sample(1:10, size = n, replace = T)
y <- dep + rnorm(0, 0.3, n = 20)

df <- data.frame(xcat=xcat, xnum=xnum , y=y)
df.hex <- as.h2o(df, destination_frame="df.hex")

#Encode as factor. You will get: a=1, b=2, c=3
df.hex[ , "xcat"] = as.factor(df.hex[, "xcat"])
```

Now I'll estimate it with an `glm` model and predict on the same sample:

```
x = c("xcat", "xnum")
glm <- h2o.glm( y = c("y"), x = x, training_frame=df.hex, 
               family="gaussian", seed=1234)

glm.fit <- h2o.predict(object=glm, newdata=df.hex)
```

`glm.fit` gives the expected results (no surprises here).

Now I'll create a new test dataset that only has `a` and `c`, no `b` value:

```
xcat2 = c("c", "c", "a")
xnum2 = c(2, 3, 1)
y = c(1, 2, 1) #not really needed
df.test = data.frame(xcat=xcat2, xnum=xnum2, y=y)
df.test.hex <- as.h2o(df.test, destination_frame="df.test.hex")
df.test.hex[ , "xcat"] = as.factor(df.test.hex[, "xcat"])
```

Running `str(df.test.hex$xcat)` shows that this time the factor encoding has assigned `2` to `c` and  `1` to `a`. This looked like it could be trouble, but then the fitting works as expected:

```
test.fit = h2o.predict(object=glm, newdata=df.test.hex)
test.fit
#gives 2.8, 2.79, 1.21  as expected
```

What's going on here? Is it that the `glm` model carries around the information of levels of the `x` variables so it doesn't mind if the internal encoding is different in the training and the new test data? Is that the general case for all `h2o` models?

From looking at one of the answers I linked above, it seems that at least some `R` models do require consistency.

Thanks and best!

Comment: You may get more answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ on why the need is there. From what I remember, R's glm does require to see the same values. By default, H2O will throw an exception if it sees new values at test time. you can disable that by calling `setConvertUnknownCategoricalLevelsToNa(true)` on  `EasyPredictModelWrapper`

Comment: Also, here's a workaround if you want to use a glm model for data with new factor values  (I did it for working with R only, so am not 100% sure it will work but you can try it quickly nonetheless  `model <- glm (.....) 
model$xlevels[["MYFIELD"]] <- union(model$xlevels[["MYFIELD"]], levels(testdata$MYFIELD))`. This will augment the levels in the already trained model with new ones only present in the test data.